# What to do with empty space?

Tags: levels

On the game I am developing, I have a very small amount of left-over space on each level screen (but on no other screens.) It is a little less than 5 millimeters (~1/5in) on the left side and bottom. It is caused by the size of blocks, etc. and a few other factors. I could center the level, but still then there would still be dead space. By the way, the player cannot go past the edge of the screen or into the whitespace, so having the level appear to extend past the screen would be misleading. What should I do?

Comment: Assuming you don't want black bars, is there any reason you don't just fill the screen with your level and present an in-game barrier (e.g. wall) to the player? It would probably look more natural than a superficial border serving no purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Center the level and then use the remaining pixels to add a decorative border which fits the style of your game interface.

You could also leave it black. Most screens have a black border anyway, so most people won't notice when it's a tiny bit wider than usual.

Comment: Great idea, but what should I use for a border? My game UI is 8-bit, and I would only have around .8 of a pixel to use. Should I use a smaller pixel size? I don't know what to do from here.

Comment: @programmer5000 That's a graphic design question which is hard to answer without actually seeing a screenshot of your user interface. And even then it would be a matter of personal taste. As I wrote, when in doubt just leave it black.

Comment: 'Towerfall Ascension' is a good example for thematic filling of border space in 8 bit aesthetic: ( no images in comments so: http://indiegames.com/2014/03/12/ThornwoodQuest.jpg or use Google image search for "Towerfall Ascension").

Comment: @Felsir Love that art style! Great reference.

Comment: @Felsir thanks, but I have only a very small amount of dead space. Thanks anyways.